# Multiple sampling from the same probability distribution is automatically independent?

Tags: probability-theory, independence, sampling

Suppose you have (a discrete - for simplicity) probability distribution: E.g., $\Omega=\{a,b,c\}$ with $\mathbb{P}(a)=0.2$, $\mathbb{P}(b)=0.3$ and $\mathbb{P}(c)=0.5$.

Suppose I have some device (e.g. a computer program, such as the `numpy` library's `randint()` function) that contains the description *"This will provide you with as many random samples from $\mathbb{P}$ as you want"*. Applying this device I obtain the sequence of such samples $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in\Omega$.

**How can I prove that these were generated in an independent way? Or how can I at least determin the probability that these were generated in an independent way? Is it even possible to do that, or is my question actually meaningless?**

(Independence is a concept that is only defined for random variable or events (as far as I know), so what would the random variable or events be, that I need to consider to make the previous question formal?)

Please note: I know graduate-level mathematics (think: measure theory), but I have trouble connecting the abstract machinery, that I know, to the real world, where you actually deal with samples and stuff.

Comment: If you phrase it correctly with all the right words and hypotheses, then perhaps... but in general and with uncareful phrasing no they might still be dependent.  Take for example drawing the top card of a deck, looking at it's value and reporting it, then placing the card back on the top of the deck without reshuffling.  You can keep looking at the top card as often as you want, and each time you do so there is a probability of $\frac{1}{52}$ of it being a specific card, but the result will be the same each time.

Comment: @JMoravitz You just completely changed the problem: If you draw things like you mentioned you are *not* drawing them from the distribution $\mathbb{P}(\text{card}_i)=\frac{1}{52}$ defined on $\Omega=\{ \text{card_1},\ldots,\text{card}_{52}\}$, but rather you are drawing from $\mathbb{P}(\text{card})=1$ defined on $\Omega=\{card\}$ (this is what the relative frequency of many repeats of your experiment will be). I've edited my question to hopefully make it clearer to the public what I'm after.

Comment: You cannot "prove" that in practice. Moreover, there is no computer program that can generate random numbers, let alone independent random numbers. A typical RNG uses some nonlinear recursion, e.g.
$$
X_{n+1}=f(X_n)
$$  
to generate a sequence of numbers that resemble ones drawn independently from a specific distribution.

Comment: @user719220 I disagree.  The deck is shuffled before we drew the first card.  If before having shuffled the deck and started drawing cards we asked "what is the sample space for the possible results for the tenth card drawn in this fashion?" we would still have had the same samplespace as before.  My point being, identically distributed random variables do not necessarily need to be independent, and this is a common example of that statement.  Once we've started drawing cards, we can talk about the result of the next card given knowledge of the earlier cards, but that's conditional probability

Comment: @d.k.o. The computer program was just an example - no need to fixate on it. I just want to know *no matter how the sample is generated* if we can determine if it was independently generated; or at least find the probability that it was independently generated.

Comment: @JMoravitz No it's not: Consider relative frequencies of the events occuring, which will be an approximation of the probability; then it's clear that in your example all the probability will be concentrated in one card which has probability 1 and not $\frac{1}{52}$ (sure,  you can model the  space as having a single card (as I did) or as having all cards (as you did), but that does not really matter). But all this anchoring in a specific example I feel really distracts more, since my question is abstract in its nature.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but basically your question is testing whether a distribution $p$ over $\prod_{n=1}^\infty \Omega$ is a product distribution, under the assumptions that all its marginals are equal, and given the ability to get exactly *one* sample from $p_N$ (the marginal of $p$ on $\prod_{n=1}^N \Omega$) for your choice of $N$ (where I assume you can choose $N$ randomly yourself as well)

Comment: If so, I would gather that unless you make extra assumptions on $p$, then you cannot do much.

Comment: @user719220 you *still* fail to understand my example.  The probabilities are only concentrated into that one card **after** the first card has been drawn.  If we have ten thousand people all with their own personal deck of cards, each performing the experiment described, approximately $\frac{1}{52}$ of them will have drawn an ace of spades on each draw.  That is happened to be the *same* people each time who drew the ace of spades is my point, that the events don't need to be independent.  You can rephrase this however you like into a different but still not independent set of events

Comment: Do not confuse the *conditional probabilities* with the actual probabilities.

Comment: Your example is slightly different. Here, you are considering the 52 point mass distributions $p_1,\dots,p_{52}$, whose uniform mixture is of course the uniform distribution $u$ on $\{1,\dots,52\}$; and your example boils down to saying that the uniform mixture of the 52 distributions $p_1^{n},\dots, p_{52}^n$ is not equal to the (uniform) product distribution $u^n$. ($n\geq 2$ being the number of samples) @JMoravitz (My point is, there is a natural way to formalize the question -- see my first comment)

Comment: @ClementC. Ah, yes! This is the abstract formulation of my question I was looking for. If you could expand that into an answer (and also let me know how exactly we can model $N$ being random), I could accept it.

Comment: Also, what exactly do you mean by "uniform mixture"? The uniform distribution?

Comment: @JMoravitz I get your example now: The problem was an ambiguity in how the setup was formulated as it left it open how the card-experiment might be carried out: I assumed a fixed deck of cards, and the experiment consist in people drawing the top card repeatedly, which leads me to the probabilities I described above. You assume the experiment consists in different decks of cards given to people who then start drawing the top card repeatedly, which leads you naturally to different probabilities. I guess this shows how dangerous real world example can be, if they are not described with [...]

Comment: [...] overabundance of detail. (Which is why I generally shy away from such examples and like to stick to abstract settings, since they are easier to communicate.)

Comment: @user719220 By uniform mixture, I mean the mixture of those $52$ distributions with all weights equal to $1/52$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to boils down to testing whether a distribution $p$ over a product space $\prod_{n=1}^\infty \Omega$ is a *product distribution*, under the assumptions that all its marginals are equal, and given the ability to get exactly one sample from $p_$ (defined as the marginal of $p$ on $\prod_{n=1}^N \Omega$) for your choice of $$ (where I assume you can choose $$ randomly yourself as well).

That is, there is a single (unobserved) realization
$$
x\in \Omega^\infty
$$
from a random variable $X\sim p$. Your task is to choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$, upon which you observe the projection $\pi_N(x)$ of $x$ on $\Omega^N$ (which is thus distributed according to $p^N$). Your goal is to distinguish between the cases (i) $p$ is of the form $q\times \dots\times q\times\dots$ for some probability distribution $q$ over $\Omega$, and (ii) $p$ is not equal to any such product-distribution-with-same-marginals.

As mentioned in a comment, I would gather that unless you make extra assumptions on $p$, then you cannot do much.

Answer (score 0):

The output of `numpy.random.randint` is actually deterministic. You can verify this by calling `numpy.random.seed` before each call to `numpy.random.randint`,
using the same parameter each time you call `seed` and the same list of parameters each time you call `randint`. You will get the same results every time.
The results are only "pseudorandom", not truly random as we would usually interpret the meaning of "random."

This is a useful feature when you're trying to debug a program that depends on "random" input, because it means you can make an exactly repeatable test of the program.

If you do not reset the random number generator by calling `seed`, the output of `numpy` is supposed to give you random variables that are independent of each other.

There is no way to prove that the variables are all truly independent. If you pull a long enough sequence from `numpy` then I believe the results will *not* be independent. There are various tests that people apply to RNGs to test whether they are sufficiently "independent" (in a pseudorandom sense), but all you get from these is something like, "The outcomes are not too obviously dependent in this particular way."